# I need to use the ith value from a column

Tags: postgresql, select

In a loop, I want to get the ith value from the table every time, I write like this:

```
FOR  i IN 1..(select count (*)  from table1 ) LOOP
INSERT INTO TABLE2
select id from table1 where column_nam in (select column_nam[i] from table1);
end loop;
end
```

For example, `column_nam[1]=HPPC003`, but it works wrong, how should I do it?

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as the "ith" row in a relational database. Rows in a table are unsorted. Think of balls in a basket, which one is the "ith" ball? Taking into account all your questions about array processing you should take a step back and read a good tutorial on how a relational database works.

Comment: What a_horse said - so define `ORDER BY` expression(s) to make this a valid question. And please don't use images for values. Post text instead. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @a_horse_with_no_name is correct in that your ideas seem to be on shaky ground. You can't have a reference for the relational database rows without anything to base it off of.

While I agree in that you should revisit the basics, I would also like to propose a solution to this particular problem; If you had another column field in the table you could use this as the "ith" counter reference. i.e. columns of Reference and Data, with 1,2,3 etc for Reference and HPPC003, HPFC002 for the Data column, where you could then SELECT Data WHERE Reference==1 to get HPPC003.

I hope this helps, and Elmasri & Navathe is a very good reference for learning the foundations of Databases.